# Regex to find values separated by commas inside parentheses

Tags: regex

Say I have this kind of text:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

I need a regex expression that matches 3 times, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3.

I tried searching for a solution for this I but could only find examples where all the matches are inside the parentheses like: "My favorite colors are (Blue), (Yellow), (Green)"

Where I could use something like this:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

Is this kind of problem solvable by regex?

Comment: It is not easy to find but there are a lot of such examples on SO. E.g. [`(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bTABLE\()\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/gImNfT/1). You may also use [`(?<=\bTABLE\([^()]*?)\w+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbTABLE%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%3f%29%5cw%2b&i=INSERT+INTO+TABLE%28COLUMN1%2c+COLUMN2%2c+COLUMN3%29+VALUES+%28%3f%2c+%3f%2c+%3f%29)

Comment: It really would help if you told us what you will be using the results for and not just [what technology you decided to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solvable, see the first comment to your question.

**.NET/Ruby/PCRE/PCRE2/Boost/Notepad++** ([proof](https://regex101.com/r/gImNfT/1)):

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bTABLE\()\K\w+
```

**.NET/Current JavaScript/Python `regex`** ([proof](https://regex101.com/r/gImNfT/2)):

```
(?<=\bTABLE\([^()]*?)\w+
```

**Java** ([proof](https://regex101.com/r/gImNfT/3)):

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bTABLE\()(\w+)
```

Grab Group 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this regex:

`[\( ](\w+)[,\)]`

It basically says:

- `[\( ]`: Match either `(` or   (space)
- `(\w+)`: Match any alphanumeric word and save it into a group
- `[,\)]`: Match either `m` or `)`

Here is the sample: https://regex101.com/r/q1B9Rq/1